# Php fatal error: soap-error: parsing wsdl. api

Tags: php, magento, soap, soap-client

I am trying to connect Magento 1 with the other platform for the inventory named "Zoho inventory" via a third-party company "kloudconnector".

The API is working fine but I still get this error.

We have tried it again getting the ***error***

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://bydoo.eu/api/soap/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity
>   "https://bydoo.eu/api/soap/?wsdl=1"

I have tried everything.

Checking the server, firewall, ports, reinstalling Magento, reinstalling SSL. and still nothing.

Comment: ws return 500 https://bydoo.eu/api/soap/?wsdl=1

Comment: yes now this parts is fixed. and still the platform are not connected